# ASP.net catch error on error page

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, webforms, http-error

I have set up my custom error page which work fine:

```
<customErrors mode="On"  redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Pages/ErrorPages/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

On `500.aspx`:

```
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.StatusCode = 500;
    Exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Code.Errors.Error.RecordNewError(ErrorType.InternalException, Exception, Code.Common.GetUserIPAddress().ToString(), HttpContext.Current);
    Server.ClearError();
```

Problem is, if the error page throws an error itself we get an ugly error:

> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

How do I fall back to a more basic custom error page if the error page itself throws an error?

Comment: One possible way would be to wrap the logic in the 500.aspx page in a try-catch block and in the catch statement, redirect to a static 500.html page with a generic error message.

Comment: @HaukurHaf tried that, but wont help if the error originates from outside that logic (for example, global.asax or the master page)

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I believe it's best practice to avoid using dynamic error pages, I'd recommend that you just use a static .html file as an error page all the time.  To log the error (which your current 500.aspx page is doing as far as I can see), you could just use the global Application_OnError event in the global.asax file.

Comment: @HaukurHaf ah worked it out!  See my answer below, the `Page_Error`  method works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out just now!  Use the `Page_Error` method on the error pages themselves:

```
    private void Page_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        Exception = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Error");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```